# Benefits of ES6 Reflect API

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've been working on upgrading some code to use ES6 syntax. I had the following line of code:

```js
delete this._foo;
```

and my linter raised a suggestion to use:

```js
Reflect.deleteProperty(this, '_foo');
```

You can find the documentation for this method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/deleteProperty).

The MDN docs state:

> The Reflect.deleteProperty method allows you to delete a property on
> an object. It returns a Boolean indicating whether or not the property
> was successfully deleted. It is almost identical to the non-strict
> delete operator.

I understand that the `delete` keyword does not return a value indicating success, but it is much less verbose.

If I'm not dependent on the success/failure of `delete` is there any reason to favor `Reflect.deleteProperty`? What does it mean that `delete` is non-strict?

I feel like a lot of the use cases for the `Reflect` API are for resolving exceptional cases and/or providing better conditional flow, but at the cost of a much more verbose statement. I'm wondering if there's any benefit to use the `Reflect` API if I'm not experiencing any issues with my current usages.

Comment: I'd say no, there doesn't seem to be any other benefits to using `deleteProperty()`. If you don't need to know wether or not the delete was successful, just using `delete` is fine.

Comment: `delete` throws in strict mode if the property is an own non-configurable property, I'm guessing `deleteProperty()` does not throw an error in such cases

Comment: What linter is suggesting that?

Comment: @Bergi ESLint's prefer-reflect rule: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-reflect Of course it's opt-in and not smart enough to realize potential use cases. Just curious if I should honor it or quiet it down.

Comment: A lot of methods that have to do with construction of an object and properties have been added to the new `Reflect` API. Even though `Reflect.deleteProperty()` does not throw an error, it is not going to delete a non-configurable property.

Comment: If using `Reflect` is preferred, you could always do `const _delete = Reflect.deleteProperty` and use it like `_delete(this, '_foo')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is reflection and why is it useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`Reflect` API exposes abstract operations staying behind common JavaScript idioms. **It's main use to provide reasonable way to forward actions called on `Proxy` traps**. All of `Reflect` methods match signature of proxy traps with the same name, so you can use `new Proxy(target, Reflect)` to create object with identical behaviour as `target` object - everything will be forwarded, including special JavaScript quirks.

It's especially important for getters and prototypes, as [third argument of many methods is "receiver"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/get)

> The value of `this` provided for the call to target if a getter is encountered.

Consider following code:

```
var target = {
    get foo() {
        return this.bar;
    },
    bar: 3
};
var handler = {
    get(target, propertyKey, receiver) {
        if (propertyKey === 'bar') return 2;

        console.log(Reflect.get(target, propertyKey, receiver)); // this in foo getter references Proxy instance; logs 2
        console.log(target[propertyKey]); // this in foo getter references "target" - logs 3
    }
};
var obj = new Proxy(target, handler);
```

When you write `Proxy`, you expect it to fully cover target object - and there is no idiomatic way to do this without `Reflect`.

Moreover, having operators as functions is convenient for functional style programming.

Comment: Reflect isn't needed in new Proxy(target, Reflect). to create a proxy that behaves like the target object you can pass an empty handler. 

as per docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler
"All traps are optional. If a trap has not been defined, the default behavior is to forward the operation to the target."

Comment: How is this any different than doing `receiver[propertyKey]` in the place of `Reflect.get(target, propertyKey, receiver)`?

Comment: @Redu With `Reflect` verbs, `Proxy` traps can catch secondary property accesses as well.